# JScrollPane painting white line issue in windows look and feel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, uimanager

See the GUI:

[image: gui]

Notice a white line between the container and the scrollbar:

[image]

Is it possible to make this line disappear?

Code:

```
public class WhitePixels {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JFrame f = new JFrame("A");

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            container.add(new JButton("A"));
        }

        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //some attempts
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(container);
        sp.getVerticalScrollBar().setOpaque(false);
        sp.getVerticalScrollBar().setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        sp.setOpaque(false);
        f.add(sp);

        f.pack();
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Windows 10, Java 1.8

Comment: JViewPort and/or together with JPanel, can you please to set the Borders here?, if this line is replaced with?, or insets inplemented into L&F

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry, I did not understand your question. I don't care for borders, viewports and opacity. All I have is a JPanel inside a JScrollPane. That's all. I tried set borders / opacity to things arround but couldn't do it. I tried some UIManager properties too, but got nothing.

Comment: JPanel has a borders in UIManager, JVIewPort also, are you able to add Borders to JPanel and/or JViewPort, line must disappear

Comment: @mKorbel Can you provide an example? I changed border of panel and the line is still there. JViewPort does not support borders...

Comment: @mKorbel all the borders are null, i.e. `container` has null border as does `JViewport` and `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Is using a different look-and-feel an option?

Comment: @Abra Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to dive into the `WindowsScrollBarUI` code to discover which part of it draws that white line.

Comment: @Abra I dived. Got nothing there.

Comment: these painting artefacts has been here commented before (8-12Y) as a side effect with ??renderer/editor??, I'm still sure that something (Insets, Borders) jumps/bounces with JViewPort inside available area (Swing can't rounding divides from prime numbers correctly, simple to add 1-2pixels as padding to LayoutManager)

Answer (score 2):

```
sp.getVerticalScrollBar().setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

I changed the above code to:

```
sp.getVerticalScrollBar().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
```

and you will see the white line is still there on the inside of the border.

This implies the line is part of the painting of the scrollbar.

I tried playing with the UIManager to change some of the color defaults:

```
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
       UIManager.put("ScrollBar.thumbHighlight", Color.RED);
       UIManager.put("ScrollBar.track", Color.YELLOW);
       UIManager.put("ScrollBar.foreground", Color.YELLOW);
       UIManager.put("ScrollBar.thumb", new ColorUIResource(Color.YELLOW));
```

but it had no effect.

I got the above values from [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) in case you want to try your luck.

So I would suggest the only way to get rid of the white line is to override the LAF and do your own custom painting, which is not a task I would know how to do.

Comment: I tried all UI `scroll*` properties. Nothing seem to have impact. I also, tried to `scrollbar.setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI()` to see if the problem stands in the look and feel abstraction. But it's not. The problem I think is in `WindowsScrollBarUI`. I tried override some methods on it, but still nothing useful. *is not a task I would know how to do*, +1 for this, I agree.